# Lua memory leak in C process

Tags: c, memory-leaks, lua

I have a C program running with Lua.

Although I try to use lua_gc() to get and control memory usage of Lua, C process memory usage is still high. The C process uses over 150MB memory even though Lua say that it uses only 4MB memory.

I also try to use my l_alloc() function to track Lua memory allocation, but the result is the same with the memory usage Lua told by calling lua_gc(LUA_GCCOUNT) and lua_gc(LUA_GCCOUNTB).

After calling lua_close() to close the Lua environment, the process memory is down and looks fine.
Therefore, I think the 'lost memory' is still controlled by Lua not C program.

Here is the sample C code.
It creates a Lua environment, calls Lua function to purge data and then check memory usage.

```
int main()
{
    int rc;
    uint64_t gc_mem_usage;

    lua_State* Lua = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(Lua);

    lua_gc(Lua, LUA_GCSTOP, 0);
    luaL_dofile(Lua, "test.lua");

    gc_mem_usage = ((uint64_t)lua_gc(Lua, LUA_GCCOUNT, 0) << 10) + lua_gc(Lua, LUA_GCCOUNTB, 0);
    printf("Lua mem usage: [%" PRIu64 "] Bytes\n", gc_mem_usage);

    lua_getglobal(Lua, "command_handler");
    lua_pushstring(Lua, "CC");
    rc = lua_pcall(Lua, 1, 0, 0);
    if (rc != 0 ) {
        printf("function error\n");
        return;
    }

    lua_settop(Lua, 0);

    // do full gc
    lua_gc(Lua, LUA_GCCOLLECT, 0);
    lua_gc(Lua, LUA_GCCOLLECT, 0); // I don't know why it has different result by calling full gc twice
    sleep(1);

    printf("-------------After GC ----------------------\n");
    gc_mem_usage = ((uint64_t)lua_gc(Lua, LUA_GCCOUNT, 0) << 10) + lua_gc(Lua, LUA_GCCOUNTB, 0);
    printf("Lua mem usage: [%" PRIu64 "] Bytes\n", gc_mem_usage);

    // infinite-loop
    while(1);
}
```

Lua sample code:

```
local abc = {}

function command_handler(cmd)
    if (cmd == "CC") then
        abc = {}
    end
end

for i =0, 2000000 do
    abc[i] = "ABC" .. i .. "DEF"
end
```

output:

```
Lua mem usage: [204913817] Bytes
-------------After GC ----------------------
Lua mem usage: [4219342] Bytes
```

The output told me that Lua memory usage is down after GC, but the memory usage of this C process is still very high (193.7MB) by checking atop continuously.

```
 PID MINFLT MAJFLT      VSTEXT  VSIZE  RSIZE  VGROW  RGROW  MEM CMD     1/1
4622      1      0          3K 193.7M 183.9M     0K     4K  18% a.out
```

Is there any solution to reduce the C process memory usage?

My environment is Lua 5.1.4 running in Ubuntu/CentOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lua faithfully frees unreachable objects by calling the supplied deallocation function (by default `realloc(block, 0)`). It looks like `libc` allocator is struggling to return unused memory, possibly due to high fragmentation. Looking at the `strace` output (I've got roughly the same numbers with Lua 5.1.4 on 64-bit Debian 6), C runtime chooses to allocate using `brk` with small increments, but no deallocation (calling `brk` with lower value) follows. However, if you insert `malloc_trim(M_TOP_PAD)` before entering infinite loop, you'll see in the `top` output that resident size drops drastically to ~5M and `strace` reveals that data segment was indeed trimmed with `brk`. Using custom allocator (e.g. pool-based) or tuning `malloc` parameters will probably help in this situation.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to change my malloc setting.